# How do hackers inject DLL files into specific folder on the host machine remotely?

Tags: malware

I read that one way to perform a dll hijacking is to place a malicious dll file under a specific folder. Then, the original dll won't be executed and the malicious one will instead. I understand this concept but I can't see how it would be implemented practically.

Every tutorial I found on the internet about how to perform this kind of attack does not cover how the dll it self will get to the specific folder. For example, (take a look if you want) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1R2FcpT0O0w. In the video he shows how he creates a malicious dll that will grant access to the shell. Then, he creates a website that contain the dll and "trick" victims into downloading the file. However, to actually move the dll file into the location it needs to be, he literally goes to the victim's machine and move the file and thats my main question.

How can you download the dll file into a specific folder without going the victim's machine?

Comment: Why all the tutorials actually get into the victim's computer?

Comment: Does this help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZLhlWUmMs0?  You'd have to get a user to execute that script, or pair it with a remote code execution bug.

Answer (score 3):

There are three different attacks in this question.

> I understand this concept but I can't see how it would be implemented practically.

You seem to understand the general part of it, but not an obscure part of it. Sometimes you can leverage a DLL hijacking to execute code as SYSTEM on a computer you don't have admin rights. For example, [Ricoh drivers](https://www.pentagrid.ch/en/blog/local-privilege-escalation-in-ricoh-printer-drivers-for-windows-cve-2019-19363/) could be used by a regular user to escalate its own privileges to `SYSTEM`. So if the system you use have the vulnerable driver installed, you can gain SYSTEM by using DLL-hijack against it.

It can be used as persistence method too, and that's something usually people are quick to dismiss. *Why is this attack useful if I need SYSTEM to perform it?* is a common complaint. So imagine you are pentesting an installation, exploit a buffer overflow somewhere, escalate privileges and get a `SYSTEM` shell. How do you keep access to that shell? You exploit the same software over and over again, until the target defenses detect it and close the door? Or you use the `SYSTEM` credentials to create a persistence method?

Here the DLL hijacking comes into play. Putting code on the `Startup` folder, or `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` is going to be detected very fast. Adding a DLL on `C:\Windows\System32` that is used by some common software (like Outlook, Internet Explorer, Firefox, et all) is more stealthy.

> However, to actually move the dll file into the location it needs to be, he literally goes to the victim's machine and move the file and thats my main question.

No, that's not how it happens. What happens is something called [Directory Poisoning](https://insights.sei.cmu.edu/cert/2008/09/carpet-bombing-and-directory-poisoning.html).

Those kinds of attacks rely on the fact that there are a limited number of installation systems out there: Nullsoft Nsis, InstallShield, and a few others. If you create a DLL with a filename that is instantiated by those installers, and have the user download it, there's a good chance that it will sit on the `Downloads` folder, doing nothing. Until the user downloads a software that is installed using the vulnerable installation program, runs the installation program and that DLL gets executed.

Nsis version 2.46 and InstallShield 2015 SP2 were vulnerable to this attack.

> How can you download the dll file into a specific folder without going the victim's machine?

There's a vulnerability on how some ZIP libraries handle folder names. It's called [ZipSlip](https://github.com/snyk/zip-slip-vulnerability). It allows the attacker to create a special zip file with relative path on some files. For example, an attacker can create a `lolcats.zip` that contain a file named `../../Startup/exploit.exe`. Jf the user downloads it to the Downloads folder, and extracts the file on Downloads folder too, it will create a `lolcats` folder, extract some files inside it (hopefully pictures of cats), and create `exploit.exe` on its startup folder. It can create any file on any folder that the user have write access.